# Change the last-modified time of a zip file elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, zip

I am trying to change the last modified time of all the files and folders present in a zip file. 
If I try the script line-by-line in interpreter, the last-modified time seems to have been changed. But the same is not reflected in the zip file.

I am using the zipfile module in python.
Below is my source code.

```
import zipfile as zp
import datetime
import datetime

def main():
    zipfile = raw_input("enter the path for your zipfile :")
    if os.path.exists(zipfile) and zp.is_zipfile(zipfile):
            time = raw_input("enter the time for which your files and folders in zip file want to be changed. format: dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS -")
            if time is not None :
                time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
                newtime = time
                time = (time.year, time.month, time.day, time.hour, time.minute, time.second)             
                print "time =", time
                z = zp.ZipFile(zipfile, "a", zp.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                z.printdir()
                try :
                    for i in range(len(z.filelist)):
                            z.infolist()[i].date_time = time
                    z.printdir()
                finally :
                    z.close()
            else :
                print "you have not entered a valid time!" 
        else :
            print " you have not entered a valid zipfile name. "

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly possible with Python's default `zipfile` module. See e.g. this question: [overwriting file in ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653768/overwriting-file-in-ziparchive)

If you look in `ZipFile` class code, you'll see that in `close` method it will just append data to the end of original zip file.
To modify file dates, you will have to use some site package like [`myZip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/myZip/1.0.1) or implement this functionality yourself.

Alternative way is to fully unpack your zip file and repack it again with updated date&time. See answers to above-mentioned question for details.