# Python -xlrd library - assert 0 <= colx < X12_MAX_COLS-AssertionError

Tags: python, xlrd

Im using xlrd,xlwt,openpyxl for excel file manipulation
i have the method below, which goes over 30 files in folder and change specific column for each row in file (some file has 5,15,17,etc rows)

The method above can be run over and over and each file will be updated accordingly.
But,
Once i'm editing file (any of the files, and editing can be even small change in one of the cells (change from A to a for instance), the file cant be read by xlrd, and i'm getting the exception below.
Any idea why?

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/ohad/automationProj/automation-linux/0_master_code_prep.py", line 154, in
>
> sanity_run_all_change()
>
> File "/home/ohad/automationProj/automation-linux/0_master_code_prep.py", line 68, in sanity_run_all_change
>
> ExcelWorkBook1 = open_workbook(config.STDFOLDER + '%s.xlsx'%suitename, on_demand=True)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/**init**.py", line 422, in open_workbook
>
> ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 794, in open_workbook_2007_xml
>
> x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 534, in own_process_stream
>
> self.do_dimension(elem)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 568, in do_dimension
>
> rowx, colx = cell_name_to_rowx_colx(last_cell_ref)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 91, in cell_name_to_rowx_colx
>
> assert 0 <= colx < X12_MAX_COLS
>
> AssertionError

Code:

def fullregression_run_all_change():

```
# FUll regression suites go over and change testes to Run

print "Go over Sanity suites and Change all Test to Run position"
ExcelWorkBook1 = open_workbook(config.UI_Suites_Location + 'STD_SUITES.xlsx', on_demand=True)
First_Sheet1 = ExcelWorkBook1.sheet_by_index(0)
Suite_List = []
for suitename in First_Sheet1._cell_values:
    if suitename[1] == "Nightly Full Regression Run":
        continue
    else:
        Suite_List.append(str(suitename[1]))
print "Full regression suites count is %s"%Suite_List.__len__()



for suitename in Suite_List:
    ExcelWorkBook1 = open_workbook(config.STDFOLDER + '%s.xlsx'%suitename, on_demand=True)
    First_Sheet1 = ExcelWorkBook1.sheet_by_index(0)
    numberofrows=First_Sheet1.nrows
    Startupdaterow=4
    dest = config.STDFOLDER + suitename + ".xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(filename=dest)
    ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
    while Startupdaterow<=numberofrows:

        ws.cell(row=Startupdaterow,column=8).value = 'RUN'
        Startupdaterow +=1

    wb.save(dest)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was,

```
assert 1 <= nr <= self.utter_max_rows AssertionError
```

in `.xls` file in Python.

Visit this link to see my answer and do change in `sheet.py` for `MAX-COLUMNS`.

[AssertionError with pandas when reading excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486558/assertionerror-with-pandas-when-reading-excel/51890047#51890047)

I think you problem will be solved... :)