# Python cant handle exceptions from zipfile.BadZipFile

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, zip

Need to handle if a zip file is corrupt, so it just pass this file and can go on to the next.

In the code example underneath Im trying to catch the exception, so I can pass it. But my script is failing when the zipfile is corrupt*, and give me the "normal" traceback errors* istead of printing "my error", but is running ok if the zipfile is ok.

This i a minimalistic example of the code I'm dealing with.

```
path = "path to zipfile" 

from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(path) as zf:
    try:
        print "zipfile is OK"
    except BadZipfile:
        print "Does not work "
        pass
```

part of the traceback is telling me: raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"

Comment: Did you forgot `from zipfile import BadZipfile`?

Comment: A try-except only catches errors that occur inside the `try`. Why would this code ever enter the `try`?

Comment: Your `try` block should probably surround the `with` block instead of how you have it.

Comment: Vsminkov; No I forgot that. But it didnt change anything:

from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import BadZipfile

with ZipFile(path) as zf:
    try:
        print "zipfile is OK"
    except BadZipfile as fail:
        print "Does not work ", fail
        pass

Comment: @FamousJameous and @Vminskov

Now it worked:

`from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import BadZipfile

try:
    with ZipFile(path) as zf:
        print "zipfile is OK"
except BadZipfile as fail:
    print "Does not work ", fail
    pass
`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put your context manager *inside* the `try-except` block:

```
try:
    with ZipFile(path) as zf:
        print "zipfile is OK"
except BadZipfile:
    print "Does not work "
```

The error is *raised by* `ZipFile` so placing it outside means no handler can be found for the raised exception. In addition make sure you appropriately import `BadZipFile` from `zipfile`.