# try combined with "BadZipFile" exception

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, try-catch

I want to run function `CelebA` from `torchvision` to download celebA dataset. I want to run this function 100 times. During running this function I'll obtain error `BadZipFile` which will stop my loop. I want somehow to prevent from that using `try` function.

So if I simply run:

```
import torchvision.datasets
CelebA(root=path_to_download,
               split='train',
               download=True)
```

I'll obtain error:

`BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`.

I want now to run this function 100 times, without stopping it:

My first idea was simply to use:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    try:
        CelebA(root=path_to_download,
               split='train',
               download=True
    except BadZipFile:
        time.sleep(4)
```

But try seems to not understand exception of BadZipFile. I read this question [Python cant handle exceptions from zipfile.BadZipFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154470/python-cant-handle-exceptions-from-zipfile-badzipfile)  but it seems that its not quite similar to my problem, since in that question they are loading zip from the path, whereas I want to download it. Could you please tell me how this `try` syntax should look like?

Comment: What is the error shown when you run your for loop?

Comment: I obtain `NameError: name 'BadZipFile' is not defined`, it seems that program doesn't understand what is `BadZipFile`.

Comment: Did you try to add `from zipfile import BadZipFile` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Actually it solved the problem.. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: zipfile - Work with ZIP archives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile).

Hard to say without the rest of your code, but I suspect that you omitted the fact that ***BadZipFile* belongs to *zipfile*** (or didn't tell anything about *BadZipFile* to the interpreter). Example:

> ```py
> >>> import zipfile as zf
> >>> 
> >>> try: raise zf.BadZipFile("dummy")
> ... except zf.BadZipFile as e: print("Caught:", e)
> ... 
> Caught: dummy
> >>> 
> >>> 
> >>> # !!! Now, except clause without zf. !!!
> >>> try: raise zf.BadZipFile("dummy")
> ... except BadZipFile as e: print("Caught:", e)
> ... 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> zipfile.BadZipFile: dummy
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
> NameError: name 'BadZipFile' is not defined
> ```

Comment: The code that I showed you is whole code that I have. I want to run 100 times function `CelebA` fom `torchvision` package but then error `BadZipFile` occurs, and that's it.

Comment: There are 2 snippets of code (in your question, date: 21/10/30), I can't know whether they were run  separately or succesively. Please post a  [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).