# How do I delete or replace a file in a zip archive?

Tags: python, zip

I'm creating a program in Python which downloads a set of files and puts them into an archive with the zipfile module.

I already found out how to append to the archive, but there are cases where the files in the archive already exist and should be overwritten.

Currently, if I append an already existing file to the archive I get a duplicate.

Does anyone know how to delete a file in an archive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete file from zipfile with the ZipFile Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788/delete-file-from-zipfile-with-the-zipfile-module)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile

```
ZipFile.namelist()
Return a list of archive members by name.
```

So it is trivial to get hold of the members list before appending to the file and performing a check operation against the list of existing members within the archive.

In addition: removing from a ZIP file is not supported. You need to write a new archive
if needed and copy over existing files and omit the file to be removed.

See also

[Delete file from zipfile with the ZipFile Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788/delete-file-from-zipfile-with-the-zipfile-module)

Comment: I think the zipfile library is very limited if it cannot support removing and overwriting files in a ZIP file.

Comment: This limitation of standard library is tracked here: https://bugs.python.org/issue6818.