# How to read gzip: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'extrastart''

Tags: python, gzip

I want to read gzip and update the content.

However, I get the error

> 'AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'extrastart''.

```
import gzip                                                 

with gzip.open("PhoneWindowManager.java.gz", "w+") as file: 
    for line in file:                                       
        if "setHdmiPlugged" in line:                        
            call = "#setHdmiPlugged"                        
            if call in line:                                
                continue                                    
            else:                                           
                print line                                  
                break
```

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue18323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extrastart` is only set if mode starts with 'r',

```
with gzip.open("PhoneWindowManager.java.gz", "r") as file://change "w+" to "r+"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Additionally, I want to update some parts of the gzip file. To do this, I think I need to open the file with w+. Are there any other approaches?

Comment: There's no way to do that with python zipfile module. You have to create a new zip file and recompress everything again from the first file, plus the new modified file. please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653768/overwriting-file-in-ziparchive

Comment: Please refer to [overwriting file in ziparchive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653768/overwriting-file-in-ziparchive) and [How do I delete or replace a file in a zip archive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917340/how-do-i-delete-or-replace-a-file-in-a-zip-archive). Hope it helps.