# py2exe: excluding parts of a package that wants to import all its parts

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am trying to run py2exe and minimize the third-party dependencies. I'm trying to include only the small necessary part of a huge third-party package but can't figure out how to prevent the package's  `__init__.py`, which imports a whole lot of stuff I don't want, from being called at runtime.

This summarizes the situation:

```
myscript.py:   from BigPackage.SmallSubset import TheOnlyFunctionIReallyNeed

BigPackage/__init__.py:            import SmallSubset, HugeUnwantedSubset
BigPackage/SmallSubset.py:         import AcceptableDependencies
BigPackage/HugeUnwantedSubset.py:  import UnacceptablyHugeDependencies
```

The problem is that, even if I successfully include some parts of `BigPackage` but not others, when `import BigPackage.SmallSubset` is called at runtime, `BigPackage/__init__.py` runs first, which then tries to import the excluded parts and hence raises an exception.  It would work if I could persuade py2exe to include `BigPackage/SmallSubset.py` but **not** `BigPackage/__init__.py`, but I'm having no luck getting py2exe to understand that idea. I've tried the following in my `setup.py`:

```
import BigPackage     # let's try a Deny/Allow approach:
options[ 'py2exe' ][ 'excludes' ].append( 'BigPackage' )
options[ 'py2exe' ][ 'includes' ].append( 'BigPackage.SmallSubset' )
# nope, py2exe fails with 'ImportError: No module named BigPackage' in py2exe/mf.py
```

...and/or:

```
import BigPackage     # this seems less plausible, but worth a try:
options[ 'py2exe' ][ 'excludes' ].append( 'BigPackage.__init__' )
# nope, __init__.pyc still turns up in dist
```

...and/or:

```
import BigPackage     # really getting desperate now:
options[ 'py2exe' ][ 'excludes' ].append( BigPackage.__file__ )
# nope, __init__.pyc still turns up in dist
```

... with no luck.  Anybody know how to work around this?

Comment: It feels hackish, but can you write a dummy `__init__.py` and put it in place temporarily while you compile?  If that did end up working you could place the `.pyc` version of that one somewhere and swap it in/out of the archive file (I presume you're using bundle_files of some level).

Comment: @g.d.d.c  Thanks, I hadn't thought of that!   I can't work out whether to downvote it for its sheer ugliness, or upvote it for the fact that it *would* actually work - at least assuming setup.py is run with permission to change the BigPackage directory, which I suppose it might not always. In the end I think I'd be reluctant to go this way, in case future maintainers try to run setup.py, get some other error midway, and end up with a crippled BigPackage.  But I suppose if I used a `library.zip` and worked out how to programmatically alter it, I could just nix `__init__.pyc` out of it post-hoc.

Comment: Having tried simply removing `__init__.py` using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788 and getting the error that BigPackage is no longer considered a package,  I now see what you mean by keeping the .pyc version around.  Yes, I guess that would work *and* avoid some of the ugliness.

Comment: My solution for now (unless a more elegant solution turns up) is (1) exclude `UnacceptablyHugeDependencies` explicitly in the options (so `BigPackage.HugeUnwantedSubset` will fail if anything tries to import it); (2) use the `compress=True` option but comment out my preferred `zipfile=None` argument to `setup()`; (3) use `zipfile` code after `setup()` to replace `BigPackage/__init__.pyc`  with a zero-byte `BigPackage/__init__.py` inside `dist/library.zip`.  And that works.  Thanks again @g.d.d.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All solutions seems hackish at best (see comments on question).  But rather than post-fixing `__init__.py` I finally settled on the following strategy of going in and extricating the specific things I need, and copying them to temporary files:

```
import sys, os, shutil

# awkward kludge to include BigPackage.SmallSubset by hand without having to include the rest of BigPackage
src = [ os.path.join( x, 'BigPackage', 'SmallSubset.py' ) for x in sys.path ]
src = [ x for x in src if os.path.isfile( x ) ][ 0 ]
shutil.copyfile( src, 'BigPackageSmallSubset.py' )
import BigPackageSmallSubset


options = { 'py2exe': { 'excludes' : [ 'BigPackage' ], 'includes' : [ 'BigPackageSmallSubset' ], 'compressed' : True, }, }

# setup( ..., options=options, ... )

os.remove( 'BigPackageSmallSubset.py' )
os.remove( 'BigPackageSmallSubset.pyc' )
```

Then I make `myscript.py` sensitive to the possible difference:

```
try: from BigPackage.SmallSubset import TheOnlyFunctionIReallyNeed
except ImportError: from BigPackageSmallSubset import TheOnlyFunctionIReallyNeed
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible without patching the BigPackage library.