# Editing zip files (in memory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I need to rename (and edit) files inside a zip file. What I'm doing so far for renaming is:

```
subprocess.call(["unzip", zipfile, f])
subprocess.call(["zip", "--delete", zipfile, f])
subprocess.call(["mv", f, f_new])
subprocess.call(["zip", "-qq", "-y", "--move", zipfile, f_new])
```

This clutters the working directory and generally seems like bad coding. Ideally I would have some way to do this inside python and preferably entirely in memory. I have looked at the `zipfile` module, however that doesn't seem very intuitive or well documented. It also seems to be missing some basic operations like removing files ([Delete file from zipfile with the ZipFile Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788/delete-file-from-zipfile-with-the-zipfile-module)). Also appending a file using `zipfile` corrupted my archive (I guess it uses its own compression).

**Is there a more reasonable way of renaming/deleting/adding/editing zipped files than system calls?**

Creating a new zip file from scratch and recompressing everything seems like an even worse option than system calls.

Comment: not related to the problem, but if you use Python 3.6 or higher, it is recommended to use python's f-strings. For your first line, that would be: `os.system(f"unzip {file} {f}"))`.

Comment: I'm stuck with 3.5 unfortunately. Any solution for a newer version would also be fine though.

Comment: format is the recommended way for <3.6 afaik

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution to that here: https://superuser.com/a/687167/1171118
It seems like you can change the filename by accessing file.filename.
In the solution the person extracted the file afterwards, but as you don't want to do that, just don't copy that step.

`os.rename` is another option, I don't know if it works for files inside a zip tho.

Comment: I've looked at `file.filename` but unless I'm missing some way to "push" an update to a zip it looks like it only affects things you extract. I don't think `os.rename` works, `os.rename("zipfile.zip/file", "zipfile.zip/file2")` certainly doesn't.