# Python - Delete files in a zip archive

Tags: python, zip, python-module

I would like to know how to delete a file in a zip archive with python and if it is possible to do it with the os module or with the zipfile module

Comment: You can find an answer using zipfile in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788/delete-file-from-zipfile-with-the-zipfile-module).

Answer (score -2):

How about extracting, deleting and re-archiving?
Whichever process you try, to delete a file in a zip, the whole zip has to be extracted.

You can mount a zip on [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/367540/tool-to-mount-a-zip-rar-archive-as-a-win-drive-and-be-able-to-read-write-as-a) or [Linux](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-mounts-an-archive-for-access-as-a-file-system), and use python to delete a file in the zip the same way as you delete a normal file. Even if that doesn't look like, in this process too, the zip file will be rebuilt.